# What are the list of OS that have Python preinstalled and which versions?

Tags: python, operating-system, installation

As I am moving from C# to Python, I was wondering if there is a list of the pre-installed versions of Python on different Operating Systems like Windows, Linux, etc...

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense.

"Linux" isn't an operating system, in the sense you're talking about. The hundreds of different distros all have different preinstalled software. Almost all have Python, but they all have different versions.

Even with a coherent single OS, like Mac OS X, each different version comes with a different version of Python pre-installed (e.g., Panther had 2.4; Lion has 2.5, 2.6, and 2.7).

And even "Python" isn't just a single thing. Windows doesn't come with C Python, but I believe you can run IronPython scripts.

Comment: @abarnert IronPython isn't available by default, and you can install CPython.

Comment: @Marcin: Of course you can install CPython. Meanwhile, I thought the IronPython runtime came with .NET 3 and later, just no interactive interpreter (and no Visual Studio integration) unless you install it. But it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such list. However, I think you can safely assume every generic, modern Linux distro will have Python installed (every recent (>2years) with Python 2.5 at least), as well as most Unix SOs (FreeBSD, Solaris etc.). Mac OS X also comes with Python. OTOH you cannot expect it from most Window machines - just a few have Python by default. This usually is no problem, however, because Python is fairly easy to install and, in the end, you can rely on things such as [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).

This is, of course, a rule of thumb, not a really precise answer. Nonetheless, I find that those assumptions make sense enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also heard that python 2.7 is in newer versions of UNIX, also do you know if a newer version of python is installed and the program runs an older version does the user must have older version of Python too?

Comment: @MohamedTarek absolutely most of the time, it is no problem. A program written to e.g. Python 2.5 will run flawlessly in a Python 2.7 interpreter. AFAIK the 2.x series is backward compatible but even if you find some little problems, they will be restricted and localized. I, for one, never found such a problem. OTOH, if the machine just has a Python 3.x interpreter (which is very improbable, since Python 3 is not widely used yet) then it will not run Python 2.x programs.